# Need of an cyclic depends_on in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have the following problem. I want to use this  [docker-compose](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-matomo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file, since it takes over the set-up after the matomo start. I want to use it during the development and need some data after the container start in the mariadb. I found the table where I have to insert a sql script which is already written. Now my problem

I need data in the mariadb, therefore I could use the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Unfortunately, at this time there are no tables, since matomo which insert the table structure waits until the db is running. The matomo container seems to have no such entrypoint which I could use.

Thus I have more or less a matomo depends_on mariadb and mariadb depends_on matomo.

I have the following question: Are there better ways than write my own image where I adapt the start-up.sh to check my own entrypoint to insert a sql script? As mentioned it is only for the development, I want to keep it simple.

Thanks in advance 
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

So we tried out some stuff.

First of all, we used an basic instanc of Matomo and MariaDb and hoped, that the configuration during the first steps has to be done one time. If this would be the case, we would make an database dump and insert it in the MariaDb during start, since there is an endpoint available. Unfortunately does Matomo need the IP of MariaDb and this IP is not the same as the localhost, it depends on the docker container, which changes every start up. Thus this approach was also not successful.

After this we found out, that bitnami changed there docker image in the way I planned it, a few days after I downloaded it. They added exactely what I needed in the [post-init shell script](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-matomo/blob/master/3/debian-9/rootfs/post-init.sh). 
Now I use the endpoint and everything is working.